# In-App billing issue while creating test account

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I would like to publish my application as In-app in android market. so far well I have done implementing one test app to test whether working or not. For that i am trying to create merchant account, as I didn't find my country in the drop down list. I am wonder that how it happens. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present market is not allowing to Indian developers to proceed on this. From India we can buy apps not to sell. We can approach some other ways like http://www.digi-go.com/android/index.html.